# FileZilla FTP Server permissions

Tags: ftp, windows-server-2012-r2

I would like to install/configure a **FTP server** on my Windows Server 2012 R2 to grant access to my clients to browse their site files.

I have used FileZilla for this purpose earlier. This time I would like to enforce certain rules on FTP access

1. **Browse** full assigned directory
2. **Deny** downloads on everything or restricted amount (in size or count of files) of downloads per session
3. **Allow Uploads** for new files
4. **Deny overrides** for existing files
5. **Add** multiple groups/users
6. **Associate** each user to a local directory path

Once I enforce all these rules on my FTP server, user from a FTP client would get only enforced rules access.

Can I achieve all these using FileZilla or is there any better approach other than build my own FTP program.

Comment: I suppose your mean FileZilla Server, right?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. **Browse** full assigned directory

Grant *Directories > List* permission.

> 2. **Deny** downloads on everything or restricted amount (in size or count of files) of downloads per session

To deny downloads, just remove *Files > Read* permission.

Restricted amount of download is not supported. But you can impose download speed limit.

> 3. **Allow** Uploads for new files

Grant *Files > Write* permission.

> 4. **Deny overrides** for existing files

Grant *Files > Write* permission, but remove *Files > Delete* permission.

> 5. **Add** multiple groups/users

See *Edit > Users* and *Edit > Groups*.

> 6. **Associate** each user to a local directory path

Use *Set as home dir* button.

[image]

Comment: This is FileZilla right. I am looking for Web based (should be able to do file transfers via browser) something like http://www.ipswitchft.com/ws-ftp-server or http://www.element-it.com/asp-net-explorer-browser/online-share/web-file-manager.aspx#overview

Comment: Any webbrowser supports FTP. Just enter URL like `ftp://username:password@example.com/`.

Comment: And you should mention your constrains in your question directly.